# Have I approached this question correctly on conditioning the components of a vector that spans a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Can someone please check if I have answered correctly for this question (consisting of two parts). I don't have a solution set to check my working with, that is why I need your help.

$$\color{green}{-----------------------}$$

$$\Large{\text{Question}}$$

$${\color{crimson}{\text{Let}}}$$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 3  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=[\vec{a_1},\vec{a_2},\vec{a_3}]$$

---

$\color{crimson}{(1)}$ Find a condition on numbers $u,v,w$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{bmatrix}\in \text{span} [\vec{a_1},\vec{a_2},\vec{a_3}] $

$\vec{a_3}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$. Therefore we can forget about $\vec{a_3}$

$$\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +t\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$u=s,v=s+t, w=t$$

---

$\color{crimson}{(2)}$ Express the condition in the form $au+bv+cw=d$

$$u=s,v=s+t, w=t$$

$$v=u+w \implies u-v+w=0$$

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all your work is correct.

P.S: I like the fact that  your post is really stylish.

Comment: Haha thank you :) Yes all my questions are like that :)